# MySQL: Order by similar column values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
Ordernumber | ProductID
1           | 49
2           | 49
3           | 1
4           | 49
5           | 7
6           | 680
7           | 7
8           | 49
```

I need to order it like below, the ordernumbers which have the most of a single ProductID should be shown first:

```
Ordernumber | ProductID
1           | 49
2           | 49
4           | 49
8           | 49
5           | 7
7           | 7
3           | 1
6           | 680
```

Hope I explained it good enough. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join,by calculating the count for each product and order result by the count column

```
select t.* from t
join 
(
select count(*) count , ProductID
from t 
group by ProductID
  ) t2
on(t.ProductID = t2.ProductID)
order by t2.count desc, t.productid,t.ordernumber
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05569f/4)